# Uploading images to database using the BLOB throwing exception

Tags: mysql, vb.net, image

I've been attempting to adapt part of this procedure that I found online (can't remember where now!). I've been trying to use this to upload images to a MYSQL database using BLOB data type.

```vb
Public Sub SQLUpload()
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionImage)
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Images (File, FileName, FileSize) VALUES (@Picture, 'Name1', 'Size1')", connection)

    'Create an Image object.'
    Using picture As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\DIR\Pictures\Person.jpg")
        'Create an empty stream in memory.'
        Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream

            'Fill the stream with the binary data from the Image.'
            picture.Save(Stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

            'Get an array of Bytes from the stream and assign to the parameter.'
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = stream.GetBuffer()
        End Using
    End Using

    connection.Open()
    Try
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Above is the current sub routine. Whenever this is executed, the routine operates fine until it gets to:

```
Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

It throws the error:

> Unable to cast object of type System.Byte[] to type System.IConvertible

I'm pretty sure this happens because of the fact that the bytes from the image are returned as an array however the memory that they are saved to does not support an array? This was just gathered from reading I've done elsewhere online.

However, as this is not all my code I am frankly not sure what the problem is. Can anyone see what is wrong with it?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have

```
SqlDbType.VarBinary ' <-- this is Sql Server DB type
```

use

```
MySqlDbType.Blob
```

Like this

```vb
Dim file() As Byte = ' set your file
Dim p As MySqlParameter = new MySqlParameter("@Picture", MySqlDbType.Blob, file.Length)
p.Value = file
command.Parameters.Add(p)
```

As it mentioned by others, you don't need to "Save" your file - just read it into byte array. My code would look something like below:

```vb
Public Sub SQLUpload()

    Try
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
            ' Parametarize entire sql string
            Dim sql As String = 
                 "INSERT INTO Images (File, FileName, FileSize) VALUES (@Picture, @name, @size)"
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)

                Dim fileName As String = "C:\DIR\Pictures\Person.jpg"
                Dim file() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)   
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = file
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fileName
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = file.Length

                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using

        End Using
        MessageBox.Show("Success")
    Catch ex As Exception
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Good catch on the MySql vs SQL Server types.